# How can I install and run Minecraft?

Tags: software-installation, games

I want to play Minecraft on my laptop. How do I install it? I've downloaded the file from the Minecraft website, but nothing happens when I double click it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an easy way to install Minecraft. Just add this PPA and install the Minecraft Installer:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Note: This is not a Minecraft / Mojang ppa, but it does install the real launcher.

The installer will download the current version of the official launcher and automatically satisfy the required dependencies such as OpenJDK, and add a `minecraft.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, for easy start-up of slingshot-launcher.

Right click on the icon and click "keep in dock". Then it will be available with links to common Minecraft resources such as the Wiki and your local folders, including Resource Packs and Screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Download the Minecraft launcher from [here](https://minecraft.net/download). You have to buy an account first, the price varies currency to currency, and normally slowly always going up.

You will get a `.jar` file:

[image]

Now, to run this you need java. I use version 1.8 currently.

The easiest way to install java is to do it with the Web Up8 Oracle Java OOS. This installs JDK 8 (which includes Java JDK, JRE and the Java browser plugin):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

You will have to accept the terms:

[image]

And then it will download and install.

[image]

Now you can just double click the Minecraft.jar file and it will open:

[image]

Finally, to add it to slingshot, you can [follow these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/263581/186134).